# Model instance not sent via link-to to dynamic route if using RSVP.hash()

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I can't seem to pass a model instance to a dynamic route if the dynamic route is model hash.

I have a companies route:

```
// routes/companies,js
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.get('store').findAll('company');
  }
});
```

And a companies/edit route:

```
// routes/companies/edit.js
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    var store = this.store;
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      companies: store.findRecord('company', params.company_id),
      companyTypes: store.findAll('companyType')
    });
  }
});
```

My companies template is:

```
<!-- templates/companies.hbs -->
<div style="width:400px; height: 300px; overflow:true;float:left;">
  <h2>Companies</h2>

  {{#each model as |company|}}
    <p>
      {{#link-to "companies.show" company}}{{company.companyName}}{{/link-to}}
      {{#link-to 'companies.edit' company}}Edit{{/link-to}}
    </p>
  {{/each}}
  {{#link-to 'companies.new'}}New{{/link-to}}
</div>
{{outlet}}
```

If I go directly to the dynamic route, all works fine.

However, in the `link-to` in `companies.hbs` I am passing the company model to the `companies.edit` route, but the data never gets to the `companies.edit` (`company` is `undefined`) I assume because `companies.edit` is expecting the model hash.

Answer (score 1):

Using Stack Overflow for rubber ducking has worked again.

Change the `link-to` to pass the id, not the model:

```
{{#link-to 'companies.edit' company.id}}Edit{{/link-to}}
```

When you pass the id, you cause the model hook to re-fire and the model hook is ignored if you just pass the model. I am not entirely sure why it seems to be necessary to supply the id and force the model hook to repopulate the hash in this situation.

Maybe Ember can't infer which model in the hash is being used or some other side effect?

Comment: When link-to is clicked then particular route transitioning will start, route model hook will be called to get the `model data`, in your case you are providing `model` itself to `link-to` so ember will assume the required model is already resolved so no need to call model hook again. Here you go for ember guides explanation https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/#toc_dynamic-models

Comment: @kumkanillam, Then why does `{{#link-to "companies.show" company}}` work but not `{{#link-to "companies.edit" company}}`? The `.show` route is getting the cached model, but `.edit` is not?

Comment: 1.Routes without dynamic segment will always execute the model hook. 2. Routes with dynamic segment will always execute the model hook only when it's entered through URL. 3. Routes with dynamic segment, if you use link-to helper to transition then you need to provide identifier only then model hook will be executed. 4. Routes with dynamic segment, if you use link-to helper to transition and if you provide model/or any object  then model hook will not be executed.

Comment: 5. Routes with dynamic segment, if you use link-to helper to transition and if you dont provide any of id/model then you will get ember.assertion error...if you still feel something is wrong then you can post the router.js file in the question